# Hudson XML error-- No module named dom.minidom

Tags: xml, dom, hudson, minidom

I am trying to send a simple XML file of the format given in http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Monitoring+external+jobs . I was able to send it easily and was getting desired result!! Then I tried to build this XML file using python script and it was giving me the exact file that I wanted without any problem. But when I tried to run this and send it to Hudson, I was getting the error - "No module named dom.minidom" . I checked again by executing in Python IDLE and it ws working fine but when I tried to send it again, I was getting the same error.. plz help..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See [ImportError: No module named dom.minidom](http://www.raditha.com/blog/archives/1759.html).

> The python script being named as
>   xml.py causes the intepreter to get
>   confused. ... 
>   Renaming the file as my_domxml.py and
>   deleting the xml.pyc did the trick.

For an explanation, read the short [blog](http://www.raditha.com/blog/archives/1759.html).